# Access SQL agregate function query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I would like to make an SQL query to extract aggregate statistics from the following table:

```
        Company | Product X1 | ProdX2 | ... | ProdX10 | ProdY1 | ProdY2 | ... | ProdY10

    ABC               5         3      ...     6           5       8      ...      12
    EDF               2        NULL    ...     5          Null     1      ...       6
     .                .         .       .      .           .       .       .        . 
     .                .         .       .      .           .       .       .        .
     .                .         .       .      .           .       .       .        . 
    XYZ             NULL        3      ...     14          7       2      ...       8
```

The result of the query should look something like this (other design suggestions appreciated)

```
Product   |   Average   |      Min     | Covariance with corresponding X or Y Product
ProdX1      Avg(ProdX1)    Min(ProdX1)    Covar(ProdX1,ProdY1)   
ProdX2      Avg(ProdX2)    Min(ProdX2)    Covar(ProdX2,ProdY2)
  .
  .
  .
ProdY10     Avg(ProdY1)   Min(ProdY10)    Covar(ProdY10,ProdX10)
```

I am OK with the different aggregate functions, of course Covar (X1,Y1) = Covar(Y1,X1)

However, I am not sure how to create a query that returns the desired result.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your schema is a bit flawed. You have a separate column for each product but this doesn't work for statistical queries. You need a table that only has 3 columns - Company, ProductId, Value. This way you would also have support for new products - you just add a new row.

Comment: Why are you pivoting avg, min, max for a product? Shouldn't it be for a company? Doesn't make much sense :$... What you need is the unpivot function.

Comment: @Justus: Thank you for your comment. I'll think about it.

Comment: @bonCodigo: Indeed it may seem strange to calculate the statistics for products, but this is what I would like to do!

Comment: @Zubai right I noticed now. 1.You want to compare each product against another regardless of the company? is that correct? 2. Can you share with us the meaning of min, max and avg in this case for product vs product? What data you want to aggregate and by what? Covariance is straight forward once X,Y is found. But in order to find X,Y what are you parameters? What is the logic based on your table given?

Comment: @bonCodigo: Thank you for looking at this. Essentially there are 2 types of products, the ones have names like ProdX1 (with an X), the others have names like ProdY1 (with a Y). I don't need the find X and Y, this is just a way to name my products.

Comment: As @Justus says, you need a flat table. You can use Union to get it.

Comment: Since you showed this ` Avg(ProdX1)` it totally gave me an misinterpretation... You need the Average number for ProdX1 and that makes some sense now... I was thinking of the unpivoting...